# More information about successful tests?

Tags: playwright

How can I provide additional information about a passing test?

`console.log` doesn't work as the output gets overwritten as the tool logs it's own information about tests. (Perhaps this is a bug?) Ultimately we cannot depend on any output making it to the final screen unless the test fails. Ideally, I want to push an object (and perhaps screenshots) to something that is designed to collect information about the test, then associate it with the test and be accessible with the output of the test.

Building a custom object doesn't work as there are internal features with playwright, such as retry'ing a test.

Here is a typical scenario: While accessing a website, a record may be created (a work order id, or a purchase order number, and various other information may be encountered along the way).

Ideally I'm looking for some object like:

`test.addInfo( someObject )`

Perhaps at the end of the test, this is dumped out, or available to a reporting tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible out-of-the-box. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testinfo#test-info-annotations

There is an optional second parameter specifically for this. The reporter would have to work  with this (json works however list, dot etc.. would not).

```
test("Some test", async ({ page }, testInfo) => {
//                                 ^ add this object

// Add arbitrary infomation like this:
   let someObject = ({ additionalTestInformation: "here" })
   testInfo.annotations.push({type:"info", description: someObject });

// Add screenshots or other files as well:
   testInfo.attachments.push({ name: "screenshot", path, contentType: "image/png"}) 
});
```